# What's a theoretical example of GDT usage?

Tags: operating-system, memory-segmentation, gdt

I am following a [walk through of the GDT](https://ordoflammae.github.io/littleosbook/#segmentation). I can get a grasp of how the data structure is implemented and it's purpose.

However, what I don't understand is how the GDT is used. What is a scenario where the CPU needs to load a segment and how does the GDT do that? If the GDT is involved in a keyboard driven interrupt, that would be a great example to explain.

Answer (score 0):

GDT or Global Descriptor Table contains information about segments of the memory. The address of GDT is stored in one of the special registers called GDTR. Each segment maps to a region of memory. The purpose of the segment is to provide hardware memory protection. The CPU does not really load the entire segment as segment usually refer to a memory region. Rather, when you use one of the segment registers (CS, DS, SS, etc) with an offset to address a memory region, CPU will perform check with info stored in GDT. For example, if you have set one of the segment to be read-only then later you try to write to it, the cpu will prevent the access. For a system do use segment, GDT is involved every time someone access memory.

Today's OS rarely uses segment. Most of them set up "Flat Memory Model" which each segment spans entire memory space. Paging and virtual memory are used for memory protection. Segment exists mainly because of backward-compatibility.
You can read more about GDT on [osdev](https://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table)

Answer (score 0):

For a modern OS that doesn't use segmentation (much); you'd probably find that the GDT contains:

- 2 or 3 descriptors for "CPL=0" and "CPL=3" code (if a 64-bit OS supports older 32-bit processes then it will probably have "32-bit CPL=3 code" and "64-bit CPL=3 code", in addition to "64-bit CPL=0 code")
- a descriptor for "CPL=0" stack
- a descriptor for "CPL=3" stack and data
- a descriptor per CPU for the CPU's TSS (Task State Segment)
- for 32-bit (not so much for 64-bit where you can use `swapgs`) one or two descriptors per CPU that are used to find "CPU local" data and/or "thread local" data
- (optionally, less likely); a descriptor that defines a call gate for the kernel's API
- (optionally, for special purposes); one or more descriptors that describe an LDT (sometimes used for emulation)

For other operating systems the GDT could contain anything.